# Troubles with JS code

Tags: javascript

I have troubles with code which must display the image within a frame 300x300px. Also there must be an ability to zoom in and out image inside the frame by pressing the + and - on the keyboard. 
I'm a mac user, so maybe the key codes for + & - is not correct, or I asked the wrong path to the image (it's in the same folder as script file). Please, help and thanks for watching! Maybe there is more elegant method to do this task...

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var speed = 4;
function showImage (src)
{
    var div = document.createElement ("div");
    with (div.style)
    {
        width = "300px";
        heigth = "300px";
        border = "2px solid black";
        textAlign = "center";
        overflow = "hidden";
    }
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    img = document.createElement ("img");
    img.src = src;
    img.width = 300;
    img.height = 300;
    div.appendChild (img);
}
function keyDown (key);
{
    var k = 0;
    if (key == 107 ) k = speed;
    if (key == 109 ) k = -speed;
    if (k != 0 )
    {
        img.width = img.width + k;
        img.height = img.height + k;
        img.style.margin = ((300 - img.height) / 2).toString() + "px";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onkeydown="keyDown (event.keyCode)" onload="showImage ('image.jpg')">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain a bit more. What works, what does not work? Does the image show but you can't zoom in/out? Does the image load at all?

Comment: The image doesn't load, and the browser is clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your console to debug Javascript. It's the F12 key on Firefox and Chrome, for Safari follow [these](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html) instructions.

The image does not load because you have a syntax error line 23, a `;` at the end of the definition of your keyDown function

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fully understood what's the problem: key codes 107(for zoom +) & 109 (for zoom -) are for windows keyboard. So I find information about codes of these keys for Mac (61 for zoom + & 173 for zoom -) and hopefully get what I want.

[image: Realization]